# Taking Array and integer as arguments and returning an array

Tags: python, arrays, function

I've created a simple distance finder function that takes 2 integers and 2 arrays. It calculates the distance as shown, and returns the distances as an array. I don't know why but I'm getting errors. Any ideas why and any advices to fix ?

```
xs = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
ys = [7,8,9,10,11,12]

def distance(t0, t1, x, y):
    distance = []
    for i in range(len(x)):
        distance[i] = (abs(t1 * x[i] + t0 + y[i])) / (((t1**2)+(1))**0.5) #the distance formula of a point to a line. point = (x,y) , line = t0+t1*x
    return distance

print(distance(3,6,xs,ys))


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ml2.py", line 10, in <module>
    print(distance(3,6,xs,ys))
  File "ml2.py", line 7, in distance
    distance[i] = (abs(t1 * x[i] + t0 + y[i])) / (((t1**2)+(1))**0.5)
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Comment: you need to use append method for distance since it is a list and it does not have any elements in that list.

Comment: distance.append((abs(t1 * x[i] + t0 + y[i])) / (((t1**2)+(1))**0.5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your list `distance` has length `0` (you can verify this with `print len(distance)`). That means that is has no indexes. You are trying to assign something to index `0`, which does not exist. What you probably want to do is [append](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) to the list:

```
distance.append((abs(t1 * x[i] + t0 + y[i])) / (((t1**2)+(1))**0.5))
```